# the least number that is when successively divided by 7,5,3 leaves successive reminders 4,4,1 respectively is

Tags: arithmetic

Options

> 172,144,102,109

my answer

> [image: Blockquote]

is this the correct way to find the least number ?

Comment: $172$ does not leave a remainder of $4$ when divided by $5$? $67$ also doesn't leave a remainder of $4$ when divided by $5$. Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: $172-67 = 105 = 7*5*3$.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need

$$  7(5(3+1)+4)+4=172$$

Work backwards. The smallest number that is $1\pmod3$ is $4$. $4$ is therefore the result of dividing by $5$, and therefore was $24$ before the 'divide by $5$ to leave remainder $4$' operation.

As the next operation is 'divide by $7$ to leave remainder $4$', then $24\times7=168$, and add $4$ to give $172$.

Comment: Why, please offer some kind of explanation to why that number should staisfy the given criteria.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity; fixed.

Comment: But the remainder when dividing $172$ by $5$ is $2$, not $4$.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity; the question in the title says 'successively'.

Comment: but 67 also when successively divided get you 441 as reminder .

Comment: Okay, if you perform the subsequent divisions on the integer part of the result of the previous division, I see why this is a solution. I understood the successive divisions to all happen on the original number.

Comment: @unknown; $9/5\ne 4, 9\pmod5$ does, but they are different operators.